# How to include dependency versions testing with pypi from python?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci, pytest, tox

I have a python module that has a list of dependencies from pypi and I do want to test against any new dependencies, so I would be able to discover when a change made to a dependency would break my module.

Example `requirements.txt`

```
aaa
bbb>=2.0
ccc=3.0
```

Let's say that on PyPi we have these versions

```
aaa=1.0,1.1
bbb=2.0,2.1
ccc=2.0,3.0
```

Based on this I expect that the test to be run at least against these combinations:

```
aaa=1.1 bbb=2.0 c=3.0
aaa=1.1 bbb=2.1 c=3.0
```

By doing this kind of matrix testing, we should be able to spot problems very fast

How can I obtain this functionality? Did anyone implemented such a thing?

Now I am using Travis CI, tox and py.test and running against 3 versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

The `tox-matrix` package on PyPI looks like what you want. Looks like it may require some more tooling to go straight from `requirements.txt` and look for available versions though. By which I mean, it wants the specific versions in a command line argument.